# Azure datafactory: My REST api call works in copy data but not in data flow, why?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to set up a data pipeline in ADF. I can't seem to figure out why an API call works as a source in the "copy data" block in the pipeline, but when I try to use it as a source in the data flow it throws an error.

This is the request in the copy data block: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wzSZ.png'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wzSZ.png%27)

This is the request in the data flow tab: : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onpuk.png

And this is the error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9zdb.png

The request body should be the same. Still I get a good response when I preview the data in the copy block: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKZsb.png

Is there some setting that is different that I am missing?

EDIT: the url for the request is https://www.daggegevens.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens with the request body `start=2022010101&end=2022090724&stns=330&vars=DD:FH:FF:FX&fmt=json`

Comment: I wish I could, but there is no actual code. It's all GUI so screenshots are my best bet, will add the request URL as an edit though so people can mimic the resources made in azure.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced same error in Dataflow.

[image: error]

- I tried to give Request body in query parameters as in below image

[image: Query params]

- Response of this API had header and body in each line item.
  [image: response]
- Thus, **select transformation**  is used to select only the body response and copied it to the sink
  [image: select transformation]

Outputs that I received from both copy activity and data flow activity are same.

**copy activity output**
[image: copy activity output]

**data flow activity output**[image: data flow activity output]